# Prolog. Two variable the same name

Tags: prolog

```
my_reverse(L1,L2) :- my_rev2(L1,L2,[]).

my_rev2([],L2,L2).
my_rev2([X|Xs],L2,Acc) :- my_rev2(Xs,L2,[X|Acc]).
```

Hi,

What does it mean that there are two same names of variable in second line?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suppose by "second line" you mean "third line", so we are talking about the clause:

```
my_rev2([], L2, L2).
```

which is the first clause of `my_rev2/3`, right?

So what does it mean that the same variable occurs *twice* here in the clause head? Side-question: What does it mean that the first argument is `[]` in the clause head?

This all becomes clear if you first introduce fresh variables and then make all unifications *explicit*. We can write the clause as follows:

```
my_rev2(Ls, L1, L2) :- Ls = [], L1 = L2.
```

And now it is clear: `my_rev(Ls, L1, L2)` holds **if** `Ls = []` **and** `L1 = L2`. Of course, there is no need to be so verbose, so we can simply pull such unifications directly into the clause head!

This may all sound quite trivial, but in fact your question is a very good one: I have seen many beginners *not* pulling such unifications into the clause head, needlessly complicating their code and at the same time (this often goes hand in hand) also making it less efficient.

---

A small note on style: I recommend to let the names of variables that denote *lists* end with an "s", in analogy to the regular English plural form. Also, it is often useful to append an underscore (`_`) to names of auxiliary predicates. So, I would write the initial fact similar to:

```
reverse_([], Ls, Ls).
```

and this, of course, is semantically equivalent to:

```
reverse_([], As, Bs) :- As = Bs.
```

Comment: Excellent explanation! Thanks :)

Comment: Could you hint me where there is resolution here?

Comment: The connection with resolution is nicely explained for example in *The Art of Prolog*, I recommend you check it out for more information.